# How to refresh Chrome

Tags: caching, browser

I'm building a series of web pages. Some have images on them. I need to update the images and view the result. BUT in the moment Chrome takes the images from some kind of cache or other mechanism. I did a test and created some html with the image. Here's the original image:

```
<p class="Regular"><img class="img-responsive"  max-width="40%" height="auto"
src="/jpg/image30.jpg" ><br/><br/>
```

That image is old. I uploaded (via WinSCP) a new image30.jpg, but the old one continues to display. I went to what I think the Chrome cache in

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache
```

And deleted all files except for data_1, _2, etc.

I went into Chrome's settings and deleted browsing data.

If I change the image name in the Html to some other name, even one which doesn't exist, an image does display, usually an older one.

This also happens with Firefox and Opera.

Answer (score 0):

You can press CTRL + F5 to reload the page without cache. Under google chrome develop tool, we have an option to disable the cache:

[image]